# How to compare within groups using pivot table/chart

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I don’t know if I’m being daft or if what I want isn’t possible with excel. But, I have a big list of student grades for an exam, and I want to be able to compare the first and second marker’s grades. So in the original table, I’ve got a first mark column, a second mark column and also a first mark grade column and second mark grade column which looks up the mark and translates it to A, B+, C etc. So what I want is a pivot table and corresponding chart which shows how many A+s the first marker gave compared to the second marker. So On the pivot table I’m putting ‘first mark grade’ and ‘second mark grade’ into values, but then I can’t put like a neutral list of grades into the Rows section, so if I use first mark grade In there, then it only counts that mark so both columns end up the same, if I use them both then madness ensues. I know I could do this by manually making a table with the grades down one side and using countifs to get the values but I want to use a pivot table if possible for the filter function to allow users to show only one class of students. I’ve googled extensively but can’t find anything so any help much appreciated (even if the answer is ‘can’t be done’ at least I can stop trying!) thank you!

Really sorry but I cannot work out how to post sample data in a way that can be cut and pasted but

[here's a pic of the first few rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ob5H.png)

[here's what i want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aduSE.png)

[with this chart but as a pivot so i can use all the pivot chart functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZR78l.png)

Comment: Hi welcome to SO.  Please post some sample data and desired output for that sample data!  please add data that can be copied.

Comment: I have added pictures of the sample data but I can't work out how to add it in a format that can be copied.

Answer (score 0):

Withpout a data example, this is a shot in the dark, but it looks like you choose the wrong design. You said you got 4 columns, and actually to benefit from Pivot Table you need just 2. As example:

[image]

You can see my data I use 2 rows per student: one for first mark, and another one for second mark. With this design, you can create a Pivot Table and ***COUNT** how many times each grade was obtained on first and second mark.

That way, you can easily see that students got more A and B on first mark vs second mark.

But as I said, you've not posted any data example and your question is kind of unclear and too broad, so this is just a suggestion.

Comment: Thank you and I can see how that would work, but I have got hundreds of students, and a lot of columns of additional data. Duplicating it all would be less practicable than using the countif solution.